# Create list of objects from csv upload

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a model called leads. I upload them via CSV. The problem is that I would like to name each of the lead lists when uploading so I can filter and view specific lists. Do i need to create another model called list and add the leads to that list.

**Models.py**

```
class Lead(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  address = models.CharField(default=0, max_length=50)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="")
  state = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
  zipcode = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, default="", blank=True)
  email = models.EmailField(default="")

  def __str__(self):
   return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

**View.py**

```
def csv_upload(request):

  template = "leads/lead_csv_upload.html"
  data = Lead.objects.all()

  prompt = {
    'order': 'Order of the CSV should be name, email, address,    
      phone, profile',
    'profiles': data    
          }
  if request.method == "GET":
    return render(request, template, prompt)
  csv_file = request.FILES['file']

  if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
    messages.error(request, 'THIS IS NOT A CSV FILE')
  data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
  io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
  next(io_string)
  for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
    _, created = Lead.objects.update_or_create(
        first_name=column[0],
        last_name=column[1],
        address=column[2],
        city=column[3],
        state=column[4],
        zipcode=column[5],
        phone=column[6],
        email=column[7],
  
    )
  context = {}
  return render(request, template, context)
```

**Csv_upload.html**

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    <label for="file1"> Upload a file </label>
    <input type="file" id="file1" name="file">
    
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use update or create, you can simply add a value with the name of the list and then you can filter by that therefore in the frontend you need to create an input and pass it with alongside the csv to the backend.

Comment: Does that mean i need to add another value to my lead model? Also how would i pass that value in my csv upload form?

Comment: 1.- Yes, you need another value in the lead model for identify the list,
or you can create other model connect it by foreign key in this new model
you only will store the name of the list and the foreign key to LEADS.
 2.- about the form, If you upload by POST, I assume you have a 
 function in the frontend to send the information from the CSV so, 
 you simply can add the value of your input form with the name of the list
 and store all in the context or you have the option to store the name 
 of the list in the filename and extract from the file.